# How to run xinit with no mouse?

Tags: mouse

When I start my app using xinit in a new terminal (CTRL+F1) my app needs the cursor to be on it, else the keyboard doesn't answer.
So, is there a way to start xinit specifing to do not use the mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the xdotool package, you can read the manpage at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdotool.
Add a small delay after starting the window and you should be able to set the focus on it from the start script.

Comment: Smells like a workaround. But maybe I use it, thanks!

Comment: It's not a workaround, it's the real solution, it's your responsibility to manage the focus from xinit process. Since you are not using a real windows manager you need to manually manage the window focus.

Comment: that's a really interesting project, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

`xinit` itself does never use the mouse, it's just a program that starts the X server and then launches 1 or more programs that use it.

I guess that maybe X uses "focus follows mouse" by default, and you'll have to unset that manually if you don't use a normal DE...?

Comment: The cursor will just appear if I start to move it. But I always need to move it, so my app gets the focus and answer to the keyboard.